# Ajax output html comment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple ajax call but doesen't work perfectly!

index.php (situated in / )

```
<?php
require 'files/config.php';
require 'files/functions.php';
include 'files/variabili.php';
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cerca-amico').on('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#cerca_amico').trigger('click');
            }
            var dati = $("#form-cerca-amico").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/friends.php",
                data: dati,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(msg){ $("#ShowFriends").html(msg); },
                error: function(){ alert("Ricerca fallita, riprovare..."); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
include "inc/testpage.php";
?>
```

testpage.php (situated in /inc/)

```
        <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" width="150" align="center" valign="top">
            <?
            $q="SELECT * FROM amico WHERE (user1='$_SESSION[valid_user]' OR user2='$_SESSION[valid_user]') AND accetta='s'";
            $q_r=mysql_query($q);
            $num=mysql_num_rows($q_r);
            if($num<1)
                echo "Non hai amici.";
            else{
                ?>
                <form id="form-cerca-amico" onSubmit="return false;">
                    <input name="cerca-amico" type="text" placeholder="Cerca amici..." id="cerca-amico" autocomplete="off">
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="cerca_amico" value="Cerca">
                </form>
                <div id="ShowFriends"></div>
                <?
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td  height="400" align="center" valign="top">
            chat
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <form method="POST">
                <textarea id="ChatField"></textarea><input type="submit" value="Invia" id="ChatInput">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and friends.php (situated in /inc/)

```
    <?
    require 'files/config.php';
    require 'files/functions.php';
    include 'files/variabili.php';
    $nome=urldecode($_POST['cerca-amico']);
    echo $nome;
?>
```

When I write " hello " on the input " look - friend " I should receive as output in the div # ShowFriends . But I never get results , I noticed that viewing the source code I get all the content of the page friends.php between comments .
Specifically :

```
<div id="ShowFriends">
<!--?
    require 'files/config.php';
    require 'files/functions.php';
    include 'files/variabili.php';
    $nome=urldecode($_POST['cerca-amico']);
    echo $nome;
?-->
</div>
```

Any solutions? I have no idea...

Comment: It seems a piece of your PHP code is commented out. It looks like the PHP files you showed are not exactly the PHP files that you actually run. Maybe the last version wasn't properly uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="ShowFriends">
<?php
    require 'files/config.php';
    require 'files/functions.php';
    include 'files/variabili.php';
    $nome=urldecode($_POST['cerca-amico']);
    echo $nome;
?>
</div>
```